# The most efficient way to export large amount of data to excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, performance, export-to-excel

If you had to get large amount data(nearly 230.000 rows) from database(I use oracle) to an excel file with asp.net, how would you do it? I need some advice about this issue.

Comment: Isn't there a limit of 65535 rows in Excel?

Comment: @sjngm, Not since Excel 2007. For Excel 2003 and earlier the data could be split into multiple worksheets. For reference 1,048,576 rows by 16,384 columns, http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010073849.aspx

Comment: in excel 2007, it's 1.000.000

Comment: @sjngm - depends on what version of Excel. For example, 2003 has that limit - http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP005199291.aspx - but 2007 can have 1 milion rows - http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010073849.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider using csv(Comma Separated Value) file format. It is very lightweight and supported by excel:

http://creativyst.com/Doc/Articles/CSV/CSV01.htm

Comment: I returned to this solution. This is very speedy. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you take a look at [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) library.

Comment: Thanks for your response. If you have also information about interop can you say that, it's better than interop? I've used interop but it was a bit slow.

Comment: @mavera, since you have the ASP.NET tag in your question I assume you want to do this server side. Keep in mind that Office automation is not supported by Microsoft on the server side, and I can tell you from painful experience that you will pick-up problems. For NPOI has proven to be very reliable and performant.

Comment: @mavera, it is a pleasure. Regarding the Office Automation, here is Microsofts view on the topic http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757.